# Archived IPA won't install onto my phone

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I've done this a few times before with my own apps.

I've started working for a client and using there account I've created the necessary files on the dev portal. Downloaded and install them on my machine.

Followed the instructions to create an archived IPA for adhoc distribution.

Drag it into iTunes.

Then drag it to my device in iTunes. When i start dragging the app icon a red badge appears, but the app never starts to sync onto the phone.

I opened the ipa and looked at the mobile provisioning file and I see that my phones UDID is
included there.

Can anybody give me some insight into what the problem may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this happen when I could see myself in the provisioning profile under its code-signing identity but I was not on the distribution profile. And the issue relied on the build settings.

Go to your project -> Build Settings and check under Code Signing. Confirm that you are using the correct developer profile. Pay extra attention to mismatches between bundle identifiers.

Check the validity of the distribution profile in the same area.

Archive and make sure you are using the correct build configuration. When creating the ipa file confirm for the correct distribution profile again.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for that. one thing that cross my mind:
Check if their device iOS version is not higher then the SDK you are using or lower then your deployment target.

I can also recommend to use Testflight service (search Test Flight iOS in google), it is perfect for distributing builds to customers.

Comment: Hi poleB. Its neither of those 2 problems. I deleted all my profiles and remade them and still the same issue -.-